# Unable to create back stack for activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, taskstackbuilder

I am receiving a notification and i want to create a custom back stack so the user can navigate through it.But as of now clicking on the notification opens the desired activity but when i press the back button it completely exits the app.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotifViewActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(StringHolder.NOTIFICATION_ID, notif.getId());

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotifActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(notif.getTitle())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Manifest File

```
<activity
        android:name=".NotifActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".HomeActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NotifViewActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".NotifActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".NotifActivity" />
    </activity>
```

The way i want it to work is,on click of the notification the user is taken to 
**NotifViewActivity** then when back button is pressed the user is taken to **NotifActivity** and when back button is pressed again the user is taken to 
**HomeActivity** .Thats the hierarchy i am trying to create,how can i do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should build your task stack that way:

```
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(HomeActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotifActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
```

Or actually because you already specifying activity hierarchy in manifest, you can do it with just one line:

```
   stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
```

Or another way to archive the same *without specifying hierarchy in manifest*:

```
    Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    Intent notifActivityIntent = new Intent(this, NotifActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainActivityIntent);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notifActivityIntent);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
```

Comment: Strangely mine was exactly like this but wasn't working until I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it!! (on emulator)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is trying to start those the created activity with `TaskStackBuilder`, follow @Divers solution and then use `taskStackBuilder.startActivities()`.

Comment: where do you put taskStackBuilder.startActivities();?

Answer (score -2):

try this :
put below code into NotifViewActivity

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("exit", true);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Comment: What is the sense in `i.putExtra("exit", true);` and `i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: And? How it's applied to current authors question? How it will add to back stack `HomeAcitivty`? How it actually will work only for cases when acitivity opened by clicking on notification? How adding `exit - true` in extras can help?

Comment: i.putExtra("exit", true); ,its optional

Comment: have you try this.

Comment: @SantoshBachkar this would always work and i was aware of this solution but its more of a work around considering there is a standard solution available.